# Фрагмент не сохраняет своё состояние после поворота

Tags: android, android-fragment, mvp, moxy

Создаю приложение с архитектурой MVP(Moxy).
Дело в том, что фрагмент не сохраняет своё состояние после поворота устройства.
Вот метод onCreate активити, в которой запускается фрагмент:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);
    String link = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_LINK_COMMENTS);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    CommentFragment fragment = CommentFragment.newInstance(link);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.comments_fragment_host, fragment).commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Вот код презентера для фрагмента:

```
@InjectViewState
public class CommentsPresenter extends MvpPresenter<CommentsView> {

private CommentsModel mCommentsModel;

public CommentsPresenter(){
    mCommentsModel = new CommentsModel();
}

@Override
protected void onFirstViewAttach() {
    super.onFirstViewAttach();
    showLoading(true);
    loadComments();
}

public void loadComments(){
    mCommentsModel.loadComments(new CommentsModel.LoadCommentsCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLoad(List<Comment> comments) {
            getViewState().showComments(comments);
        }
    });
}

public void showLoading(boolean state){
    getViewState().setUpdating(state);
}

public void setLink(String link){
    mCommentsModel.setLink(link);
 }
}
```

Вот код самого фрагмента:

```
public class CommentFragment extends MvpAppCompatFragment implements CommentsView{

/*биндим view*/

private CommentsAdapter mCommentsAdapter;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayout;


private static final String ARG_COMMENTS_LINK = "comments_link";
private String mLink;

public static CommentFragment newInstance(String link){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(ARG_COMMENTS_LINK, link);
    CommentFragment commentFragment = new CommentFragment();
    commentFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return commentFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(getArguments() != null){
        mLink = (String)getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_COMMENTS_LINK);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_fragment_layout, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    AppCompatActivity actionBar = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    actionBar.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    actionBar.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.comments_title);
    mCommentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter();
    mLinearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayout);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCommentsAdapter);
    mCommentsPresenter.setLink(mLink);
    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().finish();
            return false;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void setUpdating(boolean state) {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(state);
}

@Override
public void showComments(List<Comment> comments) {
    mCommentsAdapter.setComments(comments);
    mCommentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setUpdating(false);
 }
}
```

Загвоздка в том, что у меня есть другой фрагмент, который разработан по аналогичной схеме, но в который не передаётся никакое значение, он работает прекрасно и сохраняет своё состояние.

Где может скрываться ошибка?
P.S. В методе onCreate попробовал запускать фрагмент, который работает нормально - он также не сохраняется. Мне кажется проблема где-то на уровне onCreate активности.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `setRetainInstance(true);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло

Comment: Возможно вам вот этот совет @senecco поможет по иницииализации презентера:
https://habr.com/post/276189/#comment_8773295

Comment: скажите, а если удалить передачу параметра, сохранение заработает?

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев нет, не заработает

Comment: Как Вы думаете, может просто при повороте экрана данные из ОЗУ выпадают, там мало памяти и тп...

Comment: @KostyaM я так не думаю, мне на другом ресурсе сказали не создавать новый фрагмент в onCreate (добавить условие savedInstanceState == null и если null то только тогда делать новый фрагмент). это частично решило проблему

Comment: Я решил проблему просто запретив поворачивать экран ))))

Comment: @KostyaM данные перестали заново загружаться, но позиция прокрутки списка не сохраняется и иногда фрагмент создаётся как бы несколько раз. А запрет на поворачиваение экрана антипаттерн же)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `commitNowAllowingStateLoss` делайте обычный `commit`

В `onCreate` поищите в FragmentManager остался ли ваш фрагмент и если нет добавляйте его, а то вы просто затираете старый фрагмент, точнее дублируете его.